# Sonata Project: Can't access media that referenced to SonataPage

Tags: doctrine, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have a Page entity, that has many-to-one association to Media entity from Sonata MediaBundle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity
        name="Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page"
        table="page__page"
        >

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <field name="shortContent" type="text" column="short_content" nullable="true" />

        <many-to-one field="media" target-entity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media">
            <join-column name="media_id" />
        </many-to-one>

        <lifecycle-callbacks>
            <lifecycle-callback type="postPersist" method="postPersist"/>
        </lifecycle-callbacks>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

When I'm logged as admin - all is right and I can access media in twig with `{{ page.getMedia() }}`

But, if I open this page in Incognito window, the media of the page will be 
`null`
Any one have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this case.

If we are not logged in as admin we see a snapshot of some page, and when we add a new field into Page entity, snapshot creator didn't know nothing about this field, so we need to extend Sonata\PageBundle\Model\Transformer model

**Page.orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity
        name="Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page"
        table="page__page"
        >

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <field name="shortContent" type="text" column="short_content" nullable="true" />

        <many-to-one field="media" target-entity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media">
            <join-column name="media_id" />
        </many-to-one>

        <lifecycle-callbacks>
            <lifecycle-callback type="postPersist" method="postPersist"/>
        </lifecycle-callbacks>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

**Snapshot.orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping"
                  xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity
        name="Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Snapshot"
        table="page__snapshot"
        >

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one field="media" target-entity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media">
            <join-column name="media_id" />
        </many-to-one>
        <gedmo:loggable log-entry-class="Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

And page to snapshot transformer class

**PageTransformer.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity;


use Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Transformer;
use Sonata\PageBundle\Model\PageInterface;
use Sonata\PageBundle\Model\SnapshotInterface;

class PageTransformer extends Transformer
{

    public function create(PageInterface $page)
    {
        /** @var Snapshot $snapshot */
        $snapshot = parent::create($page);

        $content = $snapshot->getContent();

        $snapshot->setContent($content);
        $snapshot->setMedia($page->getMedia());

        return $snapshot;

    }

    public function load(SnapshotInterface $snapshot)
    {
        $page = parent::load($snapshot);

        $page->setMedia($snapshot->getMedia());

        return $page;
    }

}
```

Almost forget!!! We need to say Sonata to use our Transformer class

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    sonata.page.transformer.class: Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\PageTransformer
```